# How can javascript be inserted other than through these methods?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

What are the ways in which Javascript can be placed in a HTML page other than:

1. `<script> </script>` tags in the body or in the head tag or loaded from external files.
2. onEvent triggers
3. `<a href="javascript:code goes here;"></a>`
4. `<form action="javascript:code goes here;"></form>`

Comment: Yeah, not explaining why you'd want to know really raises suspicion.

Comment: Suspicion of what exactly? I need to strip all javascript from a sample of HTML code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `javascript:` URIs in other attributes that take URIs (img src for example)
- `expression` in CSS for IE
- Lots of tricks involving invalid HTML or malformed URIs

**Do not black list**, make sure you use a white list. Things do change. And remember that characters can be replaced with HTML entities. Do parse HTML, pass it through a white list filter, then serialise it back to HTML.

See also http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript in CSS**

Essentially, you can also inject JavaScript wherever `url()` is:

```
body { background: url(javascript: code goes here); }
```

**Image script injections** (Outdated browsers)

```
<img src="javascript:code goes here" />

<input type"image" src="javascript:code goes here" />
```

---

More can be found through XSS techniques: [XSS Cheat Sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)

Comment: The image SRCs don't work on chrome 9, firefox 3.6.13 , internet explorer 8 or opera 11.

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe there are more options - otherwise it would be easy to find security holes (XSS).

Is there a specifc thing you trying to do? or just curious ?

Comment: To strip necessary code from a sample of HTML of all javascript code.